# Parsing Json rest api response in C#

Tags: c#, json, rest, api, parsing

I am trying to pull a value from a rest api json response using C#.

I have the following code:

```
client.BaseUrl = "https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com";
request.Resource = "/v1/chats/create.json?key=" + cac.AppCode.ToString();
request.Method = Method.POST;
request.AddUrlSegment("appkey", "key");
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

In the "response" message I got a json content as follows:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "code": 200,
    "status": "ok",
    "method_name": "createChatMessage"
  },
  "response": {
    "chats": [
      {
        "id": "521cfcd840926a0b3500449e",
        "created_at": "2013-08-27T19:24:08+0000",
        "updated_at": "2013-08-27T19:24:08+0000",
        "message": " join to the chat group, welcome …",
        "from": {
          "id": "520f41e125e74b0b2400130a",
          "first_name": "Administrator",
          "created_at": "2013-08-17T09:26:57+0000",
          "updated_at": "2013-08-27T19:23:10+0000",
          "external_accounts": [

          ],
          "email": "roy@tomax.co.il",
          "confirmed_at": "2013-08-17T09:26:57+0000",
          "username": "admin",
          "admin": "true",
          "stats": {
            "photos": {
              "total_count": 0
            },
            "storage": {
              "used": 0
            }
          }
        },
        "chat_group": {
          "id": "521cfcd840926a0b3500449d",
          "created_at": "2013-08-27T19:24:08+0000",
          "updated_at": "2013-08-27T19:24:08+0000",
          "message": " join to the chat group, welcome …",
          "participate_users": [
            {
              "id": "520f41e125e74b0b2400130a",
              "first_name": "Administrator",
              "created_at": "2013-08-17T09:26:57+0000",
              "updated_at": "2013-08-27T19:23:10+0000",
              "external_accounts": [

              ],
              "email": "roy@tomax.co.il",
              "confirmed_at": "2013-08-17T09:26:57+0000",
              "username": "admin",
              "admin": "true",
              "stats": {
                "photos": {
                  "total_count": 0
                },
                "storage": {
                  "used": 0
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I pull the following nested value of "id": "521cfcd840926a0b3500449e" from the returned json response result message?

I am using C#.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-to-parse-json-in-c  ....as in, use a parser (you've shown no evidence of that at the moment). There are probably other threads relating to this too. Have you tried searching? If so, why didn't the results work?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

1> Add this namspace.
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

2> use this source code.

```
JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(response);                   
JObject ojObject = (JObject)joResponse["response"];
JArray array= (JArray)ojObject ["chats"];
int id = Convert.ToInt32(array[0].toString());
```

Comment: 2 days... that's how long i have been looking for an answer that works. And here it is. Thank you

Comment: Finally!! This is the only answer which really works!

Comment: My json was similar to this, so had to modify this code a bit, but yeah, it really helped. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 34):

1. Create classes that match your data,
2. then use JSON.NET to convert the JSON data to regular C# objects.

Step 1: a great tool - http://json2csharp.com/ - the results generated by it are below

Step 2: `JToken.Parse(...).ToObject<RootObject>()`.

```
public class Meta
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string method_name { get; set; }
}

public class Photos
{
    public int total_count { get; set; }
}

public class Storage
{
    public int used { get; set; }
}

public class Stats
{
    public Photos photos { get; set; }
    public Storage storage { get; set; }
}

public class From
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
    public List<object> external_accounts { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string confirmed_at { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string admin { get; set; }
    public Stats stats { get; set; }
}

public class ParticipateUser
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
    public List<object> external_accounts { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string confirmed_at { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string admin { get; set; }
    public Stats stats { get; set; }
}

public class ChatGroup
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<ParticipateUser> participate_users { get; set; }
}

public class Chat
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public From from { get; set; }
    public ChatGroup chat_group { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public List<Chat> chats { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Dude, the json2csharp website is amazing! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I am doing the same thing but it seems it violates the `C#` Coding Convention like `properties without a capital letter starting.` Can you recommend how to make this example even better?

Answer (score 1):

Create a C# class that maps to your Json and use `Newsoft JsonConvert` to Deserialise it.

For example:

```
public Class MyResponse
{
    public Meta Meta { get; set; }
    public Response Response { get; set; }
}
```